# How do I figure out pixel to point conversion on specific iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to upload 256 x 256 images from my iOS app. I've resized an image to `CGSize(width: 256, height: 256)`, but it gets uploaded as 768 x 768. This makes sense, because on my iPhone X, 1 point is 3 pixels.

This isn't consistent though. On some iPhones, 1 point is 2 pixels.

How do I figure out to use `CGSize(width: 128, height: 128)` or `CGSize(width: 86, height: 86)`?

Comment: Show your code for creating the image. Are you using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`? Look at the documentation for its parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use the `scale` property of `UIScreen`.

But you probably don't need that depending on how your image is created. Given your tags, it is likely you are using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Note its third parameter of `scale`. If you pass `0` you get the device's scale. But in your case you want a scale of `1`.

Answer (score 6):

Scale is points / pixels.  Get Scale in swift 5

```
let myScaleVariable = UIScreen.main.scale
```